# Indexing by sort key in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table where I'm aggregating CDN access logs. Specifically I want to track:

> For a given customer (all of whose requests can be identified from the URL being downloaded), how many bytes were delivered on their behalf each day?

I have a primary partition key on `customer` and a primary sort key on `time_bucket` (day). This way given a customer I can say "find all records from March 1st, 2021 to March 31st, 2021" for instance. So far, so good

The issue arose when I wanted to start deleting old data. Anything older than 5 years should be dropped from the database.

Because the partition key ***isn't*** on `time_bucket`, there's no easy way to say "retrieve ***all*** records for May 25th, 2016". Doing so requires a scan instead of a query, and scans are out of the question (unusably slow given how much data I'm handling)

I don't want to swap the partition key and sort key for two reasons:

- When processing new data to add to the Dynamo table, ***all*** new CDN logs will be for the same day. This means that my table will be unbalanced: every write operation made during a single day will hit the same partition key
- If I wanted to pull a month's worth of data for a single customer I would have to make 30 queries -- one for each day of the month. This gets even worse when pulling a year of data, or 3 years of data

My first thought was "just add an index on the `time_bucket` column", but when I tried this I got an error:

> Attribute Name is duplicated: time_bucket (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: PAN9FVSEMBBJT412NCV013VURNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)

It seems like DynamoDB does not allow you to create an index on the sort key. So what's the proper solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to handle this is to simply set a 5yr [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) on the records when you put them in DDB.

Not only will the records be removed automatically, but the removal is free.  No WCU is consumed.

You could add TTL now, but you're going to have to put together a little utility to add a expiration time attribute to the existing records.

If you want to do it manually, you'll need add Global Secondary Index (GSI).  You could do so with the existing `timebucket` as the GSI hash key.  Then you'd
Query(GSI, hk='2016-05-01') to find the records and DeleteItem() for each one.

Note that a GSI has it's own costs, and you'll pay to read the GSI and delete from the table.

Comment: Making a GSI is what I was attempting to do (you'll note I said that I attempted to create an "index" on time_bucket -- I should have been specific and meant I was creating a Global Secondary Index with a partition key of time_bucket) and Dynamo was throwing an error. Hence this post -- trying to figure out how to make a GSI on the sort key, since I was getting an "attribute name already exists" error. Weirdly upon refreshing the page I was able to try and create the same index and didn't get the error. I think the web UI was in a weird state this morning...

Answer (score -1):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database to allow quick **Lookup** operations and not analytical ones such as pulling a whole month of data. You can probably do that one way or another, but you shouldn't.
Replicate your records from DDB to S3 (using DynamoDB Streams and Kinesis Firehose for a serverless option) and then query the data using Amazon Athena. You will get a rich analytical SQL interface that is very low cost and scalable. You don't need to delete old data for no reason. It will also reduce your DynamoDB costs, as you can store there only the data that you need for lookups, for 30 days, for example.

Comment: We're not querying raw data - we're aggregating data. That's why Dynamo felt like a good option. Athena is great when you want to query the raw data. In our case whenever a new CloudFront log hits S3 we trigger a Lambda which parses the log file into 100 or so "update" operations to update a running sum of total bytes consumed by a customer. In general use case we're then doing lookups (for a given customer, for a given date, look up that sum of total bytes) and this is **incredibly** efficient, fast, and cheap. It's only when we want to delete data that we have a problem

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. The Time-to-Live (TTL) option for DDB records mentioned above should give you what you need.